# Pulling numbers out of a string using bash scripting

Tags: scripting

I feel like this should should have a simple answer somewhere but i haven't been able to find it so I'm asking here.

I want to write a script that disables my wireless usb keyboard using `xinput --disable`.

I have gotten as far as `xinput list | grep 2.4G\ Composite\ Devic` which outputs the following.

`↳ 2.4G Composite Devic id=29   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

Now I am stuck on how to get the in this case 29 after the `id=` in plain number form that can be piped to `xinput --disable`

Comment: That works thx for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments for `xinput` options accept device names as strings:

```
$ xinput --list --id-only '2.4G Composite Devic'
29
$ xinput --disable '2.4G Composite Devic' # Equivalent to 'xinput --disable 29'
```

- Must be the complete name (cannot contain wildcards or regex patterns)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you still need the regular expression, here is the perl-based solution:

```
echo "↳ 2.4G Composite Devic id=29   [slave  keyboard (3)]" | perl -pe 's/.*id=(\d+)\s.*/$1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
echo "2.4G Composite Devic id=29   [slave  keyboard (3)]" | awk '{gsub(/id=/,"",$4); print $4}'
29
```

Using `sed`:

```
echo "2.4G Composite Devic id=29   [slave  keyboard (3)]" | sed 's/.*id\=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
29
```

Using grep:

```
echo "2.4G Composite Devic id=29   [slave  keyboard (3)]" | grep -Eo 'id=[0-9]+' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
29
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a superset of `grep` here, so you could do:

```
xinput list |
  sed -n '/.*2\.4G Composite Devic.*id=\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
```

If your `sed` supports `-E` for extended regexps, that becomes a bit more legible:

```
xinput list |
  sed -nE '/.*2\.4G Composite Devic.*id=([[:digit:]]+).*/\1/p'
```

With `grep` implementations that support `-o` (to output the matched portion) and `-P` for PCRE:

```
xinput list | grep -Po '2\.4G Composite Devic.*id=\K\d+'
```